# Can the Careers data be queried?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, data-explorer

If jobs were like SO posts, I'd love to see something like

```
select top 500
tags.tagname, count(posts.id) as nposts
from posts, posttags, tags 
where
year(posts.creationdate)=2013
and posts.id = posttags.postid
and posttags.tagid=tags.id
group by tags.tagname
order by count(posts.id) desc
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it. Even with URL hacking I still get a 404: http://data.stackexchange.com/careers/queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible unless you are a developer at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Can we have an explanation why? It seems like it would be a really cool thing to have around.

Comment: We actually have an internal version of the data explorer for this, but no one has taken the time to clean up all the stuff we cannot show in order to make this public.  Instead of doing that however, I'd much prefer to just expose some stats on the job search interface like we do for candidate search.

Comment: I'd certainly settle for the stats, while we wait for the explorer.  (While I'm asking for free stuff!)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a way to query and view data, you could use the [RSS feed](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed). It supports a paging `pg=N` parameter, like so: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?pg=2

You could crawl all active jobs, store the data yourself, and query away.